# Change matrix elements from vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix M containing just zeros. Now I have two arrays. The first one contains the indices of the matrix which need to be changed and the second one contains the values to which the elements of the matrix at those indices needs to be changed.

Let's say:

```
mat_A = zeros(50, 50);
vec_indices = [4; 5; 2500];
vec_values  = [1; 1; 1];
```

Now if I say `M(4), M(5) or M(2500)`, I want the result to be 1 in all cases.

Is there a simple "one-liner" that get's this task done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

```
mat_A(vec_indices) = vec_values
```

Note that this only works like this for [linear indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511), so when you flatten your 50x50 matrix into one 2500x1 vector.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and got `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals`

Comment: It works on my computer. Please post a complete example that gives you the error message.

Comment: hm...you're right, my simple example works fine for me as well...I'm reading the two vectors with `textread`. They are `<280x1 double>`

Comment: `[vec_1, vec_2] = textread('test.txt', '%u %u');` When I try: `mat_A(vec_1) = vec_2`, I get the error message above. The two vectors contain the correct values...

Comment: Ok...my mistake was that this first vector contained the index 0...sorry!